# Does Grails command object support multiple MultipartFile?

Tags: grails, multipart, command-objects

I want to store multiple image in Grails application. So, command object of grail support multiple MultipartFile files.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something like that?

```
class ImageUploadCommand implements Validateable {
    List<MultipartFile> images
}
```

Comment: I wrote the relevant data binder and I am a little surprised that works myself.  ;)

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I successfully use the mentioned approach in my project :)

Comment: There is also a built in converter to bind `MultipartFile` to `byte[]`.